# DataAnnotation in Universal App

Tags: win-universal-app

I have used Data Annotations in my project, but in the universal app, it shows an error for there is no namespace for DataAnnotations.

Is "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" supported in Unversal App ?

Comment: Ah! I can't believe this is missing. Sadness :(

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it.  [According to their roadmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  You'll have to scroll down to the bottom table to see that it's available for every platform but the phone.  :(

Comment: Don't read this as a roadmap. Read this as an 'as-is' for now.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is support in Windows Universal app, sample code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SystematixIndia.Universal.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides extensions for the <see cref="Enum" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the display name attribute as a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="en">The enum.</param>
        /// <returns>The display name attribute as a string</returns>
        public static string ToDisplayNameAttribute(this Enum en)
        {
            return en.GetType().GetMember(en.ToString()).First().GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().GetName();
        }
    }
}
```